# Create link/button on Tags page to go to Tag synonyms page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms

We shouldn't need 4 mouse clicks to get to the Tag Synonyms page.

How about a link or button on the Tags page to take you right to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added a link at the bottom of the tags page.

Should help people find it.

Comment: With the layout we have now I agree that a link or button would work better, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Lance to be deployed today

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it's so very convenient.