# Are you aware of the tag synonymization page?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I almost never even think about synonymization. Why? Maybe because the link is almost hidden on the bottom of the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags#tags-legend):

[image: Synonymize link]

#### Can we please make that feature more prominent? Maybe put it on the review page.

I am sure there are some [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) waiting to be voted on. Let's get the tag jungle organized.

Comment: On the same note, why can't we vote directly from the tag synonyms list? Also - could be a nice feature to be able to filter out tags you can't vote on in case you don't have the required score for them.

Comment: +1 for tag synonyms being on review.

Comment: @Leeor: the second feature already exists. It's the "Suggested" tab in the tag synonyms page.

Comment: Synonyms on review wouldn't be helpful because there's a tag-specific minimum reputation gate for actually voting on synonyms.  That severely reduces the available reviewing audience for any given synonym, especially for tags that aren't high-traffic.  This isn't *just* a discoverability problem...

Comment: @Charles Well, they could be filtered, and pop out only for a user that can vote on them.

Comment: I agree, but [it's better than it used to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60419/create-link-button-on-tags-page-to-go-to-tag-synonyms-page).

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that *just* increased visibility will help much here. There are still way too many pending synonyms, and not all can be voted on by any given user. If that can be fixed, then increased visibility would be a big plus.

A filter that lets you see the ones you can vote on could help improve this page a lot. A review queue might be overkill, but it would effectively accomplish the same thing.

One way to go about this is to have periodic synonyming parties where users gather in a chatroom and discuss/vote upon synonyms. Over here, if the vote is falling short due to lack of users with activity in the tag, you can have a couple of mods using the synonym tool if there is enough consensus from the broader community in the chatroom.

Alternatively, relax the requirements to be able to vote on a synonym.

Comment: [Review Queue Feature Request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754/13295)

Comment: Synonyms that you can vote on are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested).

Answer (score 3):

I've created a query on data.SE which personalizes the synonym list:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/159698/my-list-of-tag-synonyms-which-permit-voting

Maybe adding a tool for synonyms on https://stackexchange.com/filters would help.