# Tag synonym: cpu-architecture (and other lazy synonyms)

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I have a suggested tag synonym that's been hanging out there for over 2 months with zero votes ([cpu-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cpu-architecture/synonyms) --> [computer-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/computer-architecture/synonyms)), would be happy for any assistance there.

Now, I'm pretty sure posting this here would get enough help from users who can vote on it, but that still won't solve the fundamental problem - some synonyms get stuck for ages, and I don't really think we should bother everyone here on MSO on every single case like this with "questions" that are actually just requests (Yeah, this one included, although I did wait for over 2 months to give it a chance).

So, it's pretty [obvious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms) that the synonym system isn't always working as it should (I'm also very fond of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210564/are-you-aware-of-the-tag-synonymization-page) showing why), and I completely agree that a review queue (as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202754/give-tag-synonyms-their-own-review-queue)) is the right way to give synonyms a better exposure, but assuming it's not going to happen soon - is there any other way to manually/automatically "promote" a slow-going synonym other than publishing it here?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that there isn't anyone that meets the requirements to vote: "Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms."

Comment: Plenty of folks here - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cpu-architecture/topusers, they just don't browse the tag synonym pages probably (at least not regularly).